# coffee-rails-source-maps doesn't create public/assets/source_maps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm trying to use the coffee-rails-source-maps gem to create source maps for my coffeescript files. I'm following the instructions here:

https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps

I have the following versions:

Rails 4.0.0
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

I've added the following to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-rails-source-maps'
gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
```

And run the following:

```
bundle update
bundle install
rm -rf tmp/cache/assets
```

I've restarted the server (thin-1.6.2),  and loaded a page, which I think should trigger regeneration of assets. I still have no 'assets/source_maps' in my public directory. Any further suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here's step by step instructions:

- Add the gems to the Gemfile

> ```
> group :development, :test do
>   gem 'coffee-rails-source-maps' 
>   gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
> end
> ```

- run `bundle`
- run `rm -rf tmp/cache/assets`
- In Chrome Browser, click on Menu icon(top-right), select `Tools >> Developer Tools` 
  This will open the Chrome developer console at the bottom of current browser window.
- Select `Settings` icon(Gear icon on the console top-right)
  Make sure that `Enable JS source maps` and `Enable CSS source maps` are `CHECKED`.
- Clear the entire Browser cache from `the beginning of time` 
  Click on Menu icon(top-right), select `Settings >> Show advanced settings >> Clear Browsing Data button(Under Privacy)`
- Close the browser(on Mac rt-click on Chrome icon and select Quit). I prefer doing this whenever I clear the browser cache as it gives me a clean state. Its not mandatory.
- Restart the rails server.

You should see `assets/source_maps` in the Rails `public` directory.

**NOTE :** As per the Official Documentation **[Help! I'm Not Seeing Maps!](https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps#help-im-not-seeing-maps)**

> Make sure you've deleted tmp/cache/assets, restarted your server,
>   enabled source maps in Chrome, and cleared its cache.

Comment: thanks for your response - as I said, I've done all the steps (excluding the ones for Chrome, which won't affect the contents of the Rails project directory), where I'm having trouble is with the last part: "You should see assets/source_maps in the Rails public directory."

Comment: It does affect. I have tried 3 times like yours and directory wasn't created . I was surprised too BUT the moment I did the Chrome steps, it worked like a charm. Try it at least once.

Comment: And it is mentioned in the official documentation as well. See here https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps#using-source-maps-in-chrome  and  https://github.com/markbates/coffee-rails-source-maps#help-im-not-seeing-maps

Comment: You may be correct on that point, I'm not sure. I did have source maps enabled in Chrome but my issue turned out to be something else. Once I resolved my issue the directory got created regardless of whether I had the source maps enabled in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

My issue had to do with the fact that my environment had a custom name ('local' instead of 'development'). The documentation for the gem does suggest using source maps only in the development environment, but does not say that the source_maps directory will only be created if the environment is called 'development', which is in fact the case. The entire compilation process is wrapped in a conditional block:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  require 'coffee-script' #make sure CoffeeScript is loaded before we overwrite it.
  #### etc ####
end
```

In summary, source maps will only be created if the environment is named 'development'.

Comment: I didn't need the 'local' environment so I just removed the configuration file for it. I ran into some trouble because I had set the following in my .bash_profile:<br/>

Comment: oops - I had set the following in my .bash_profile: `export RAILS_ENV=local` this value's default is development, so this line can be removed altogether, though I'm keeping it to remind me if I need a special env name again. For that matter, if I wanted to keep the original value of 'local', I would override `Rails.env.development?` to return true for the 'local' environment as well as the development environment